# item.appendChild is not a function

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

I know this is a very common error but I have read and read and can't figure it out why. It's probably something very easy but I can't solve it by myself.

```
var item = document.createElement("div").className = "item";
var img = document.createElement("img").src = imgpath + $(this).attr("href");;
item.appendChild(img);
```

Any help is appreciated!

EDIT:

```
var item = document.createElement("div");
item.className = "item";
var img = document.createElement("img");
img.src = imgpath + $(this).attr("href");
item.append(img);
```

This throws the same error.

Comment: Can you show an example (including some HTML, something that shows that `this` is) that demonstrates the problem? With reasonable dummy HTML, the second example works here: http://codepen.io/paulroub/pen/RPwrBV  (after correcting `append()` to `appendChild()`)

Comment: Oh man... It works! I'm sure I had tried it already! Sometimes my debugger does not refresh and that combined with poor sleeping may have caused the problem. Meh I know I have tested, I must be going crazy. Sorry for bothering you all with such stupid question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case you are creating a div and assigns it a class name, and the same value(class name) is assigned to the `item` variable. So it is a string value which does not have the `appendChild` method.

```
var item = document.createElement("div");
item.className = "item";
var img = document.createElement("img");
img.src = imgpath + $(this).attr("href");;
item.appendChild(img);
```

The same concept applies to `img` also

Answer (score 1):

Problem is here

```
document.createElement("div").className = "item"
```

it will return a `string` which won't have a method called `appendChild` on it. You don't have any reference to the created `div`.

You should be doing like this

```
var item = document.createElement("div");
item.className = "item";

var img = document.createElement("img");
img.src = imgpath + $(this).attr("href");
item.appendChild(img);
```

Answer (score 0):

Because item is the string "item", not an element. You need to break it up.

```
var item = document.createElement("div");
item.className = "item";
```

Same thing needs to happen with the image.

Answer (score 0):

`document.createElement("div").className = "item";` returns a string, not a DOM node, so it knows nothing about `.appendChild()`. Try this instead:

```
var item = document.createElement("div");
item.className = "item";
var img = document.createElement("img");
img.src = imgpath + $(this).attr("href");
item.appendChild(img);
```